# Crashlytics show credentials only for some crashes for Android devices

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

When users log into our application, we set email and id of the user using:

```
           Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(id);
           Crashlytics.setUserEmail(email);
```

But these credentials rarely occur in crash reports.

Is there anything specific about setting the credentials? Should we set them up with every app start or is there any other trick to it?

Thank you for any help.

Currently using Crashlytics library v2.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. When using the user identifiers, you need to set those on each app session or launch of the app, we don't store those across multiple sessions.